# Using SAS and mkdir to create a directory structure in windows

Tags: windows-xp, cmd, sas, mkdir

I want to create a directory structure in Windows from within SAS.  Preferably using a method that will allow me to specify a UNC naming convention such as:

```
\\computername\downloads\x\y\z
```

I have seen many examples for SAS on the web using the DOS `mkdir` command called via `%sysexec()` or the `x`command.  The nice thing about the mkdir command is that it will create any intermediate folders if they also don't exist.  I successfully tested the below commands from the prompt and it behaved as expected (quoting does not seem to matter as I have no spaces in my path names):

```
mkdir \\computername\downloads\x\y\z
mkdir d:\y
mkdir d:\y\y
mkdir "d:\z"
mkdir "d:\z\z"
mkdir \\computername\downloads\z\z\z
mkdir "\\computername\downloads\z\z\z"
```

The following run fine from SAS:

```
x mkdir d:\x;
x 'mkdir d:\y';
x 'mkdir "d:\z"';
x mkdir \\computername\downloads\x;
x 'mkdir \\computername\downloads\y';
```

But these do not work when run from SAS,eg:

```
x mkdir d:\x\x;
x 'mkdir d:\y\y';
x 'mkdir "d:\z\z"';
x mkdir \\computername\downloads\x\y\z ;
x 'mkdir "\\computername\downloads\z"';

** OR **;

%sysexec mkdir "\\computername\downloads\x\y\z ";

** OR **;

filename mkdir pipe "mkdir \\computername\downloads\x\y\z";
data _null_;
  input mkdir;
  put infile;
run;
```

It does not work.  Not only this but the window closes immediately even though I have `options xwait` specified so there is no opportunity to see any ERROR messages.  I have tried all methods with both the UNC path and a drive letter path, ie. `D:\downloads\x\y\z`.

If I look at the error messages being returned by the OS:

```
%put %sysfunc(sysrc()) %sysfunc(sysmsg());
```

I get the following:

```
-20006 WARNING: Physical file does not exist, d:\downloads\x\x\x.
```

Looking at the documentation for the `mkdir` command it appears that it only supports creating intermediate folders when 'command extensions' are enabled.  This can be achieved with adding the `/E:ON` to `cmd.exe`.  I've tried changing my code to use:

```
cmd.exe /c /E:ON mkdir "\\computername\downloads\x\y\z"
```

And still no luck!

Can anyone tell me why everyone else on the internet seems to be able to get this working from within SAS except for me?  Again, it works fine from a DOS prompt - just not from within SAS.

I'd prefer an answer that specifically address this issue (I know there are other solutions that use multiple steps or `dcreate()`).

I'm running WinXP 32Bit, SAS 9.3 TS1M2.  Thanks.

Comment: It's not just you, I haven't had any luck with X and UNC paths.  I wonder if it has something to do with the network setup, where some networks prevent it from working properly.

Comment: I'm going to submit this problem to SAS tech support as well.  Maybe they've seen it before.

Comment: I just tried running some tests on my co-worker's computers and it all ran fine for them.  It looks like it's something specifically weird with my machine. Thanks all for the help. I'll respond if I ever figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `mkdir` option `-p` which will create all the sub folders

i.e.

```
x mkdir -p "c:\newdirectory\level 1\level 2";
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a trick that uses the LIBNAME statement to make a directory

`options dlcreatedir;
libname newdir "/u/sascrh/brand_new_folder";`

I believe this is more reliable than an X statement.

Source: [SAS trick: get the LIBNAME statement to create folders for you](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2013/07/02/use-dlcreatedir-to-create-folders/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm on WinXP as well, using SAS 9.3 TS1M1.  The following works for me as advertised:

```
122  options noxwait;
123  data _null_;
124    rc = system('mkdir \\W98052442n3m1\public\x\y\z');
125    put rc=;
126  run;

rc=0
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           1.68 seconds
      cpu time            0.03 seconds
```

That's my actual log file; "public" is a Windows shared folder on that network PC and the entire path was created.  Perhaps using the `SYSTEM` function did the trick.  I never ever use the X command myself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bob. Unfortunately I still have the same problem with this approach.  I'm getting a return code of 1 and no folders get created.  I tried as both UNC and 'drive' notations and I've rebooted.

Comment: I must be something strange about your PC.  I've tried may variations but cannot reproduce the error message you received.  The closest I came was when I tried to reference a non-existing network share with UNC (\\W98052442n3m1\publicX\x\y\z), but that gave "The netowrk path was not found".  I use UNC paths all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote your x commands, e.g.

```
x 'mkdir "c:\this\that\something else"' ;
```

Also, I've never had a problem using UNC paths, e.g.

```
x "\\server.domain\share\runthis.exe" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work just fine with the dos window remaining open.  You may need the XSYNC option.  I am using 9.3 TS1M1 64 bit under VMWARE on a MAC:

```
options xwait xsync;
x mkdir c:\newdirectory;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That also works fine for me but it doesn't solve my problem.